# Where is the flaw in my stability analysis of this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The ODE $${d^2x\over dt^2}=-kx$$ can be converted in the system of linear equations as
$$\begin{align}
{dx\over dt} & =v\\
{dv\over dt} &= -kx\\
\end{align}$$

Using Euler’s method, given $x_n$ and $y_n$ and for the time step $\Delta t$, the next values can be determined as 
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
x_{n+1}\\
v_{n+1}\\
\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&\Delta t\\
-k\Delta t&1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x_n\\
v_n\\
\end{matrix}\right].$$

Now the absolute value of the (possibly complex) eigenvalues should be less than $1$ for this algorithm to be stable. But the eigenvalues turn out to be $1\pm i\sqrt{k}\Delta t$ whose absolute values are strictly greater than $1$ for any nonzero time-step $\Delta t$.

So the algorithm should not work for any value of $\Delta t$, however small. But clearly, this is not the case as my programs do come up with (an approximate) solution though.

So where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: It looks like you're reasoning in a sort of Banach-fixed-point-theorem manner: if the mapping represented by your transition matrix is contractive, then you're guaranteed a fixed point, and the iterative process will converge. However, it's not nearly so clear what happens if your mapping is not contractive. Do you know if the mapping is not a contraction, that the iterative process will not converge?

Comment: I’ve no idea of these technical things. I was just introduced to von Neumann stability analysis for PDE’s. And I just wanted to see if I could apply a similar concept here for ODE’s as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler method is indeed not stable for this problem, as the stability analysis states. To see this in the case $k=1$, note that the matrix
$$
A = \left[\begin{matrix}
1&\Delta t\\
-\Delta t&1
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
satisfies $A^TA = (1 + (\Delta t)^2) I$. That is, $\|(x_{n+1}, v_{n+1})\|^2 = (1 + (\Delta t)^2) \|(x_n,v_n)\|^2$.

Run your approximation long enough and watch the solution spiral out to infinity. Specifically, run it to time $T = (\Delta t)^{-1}$.

Comment: It's worth noting that the method is *convergent* in the sense that  as you take $\Delta t \to 0$, the approximation at a fixed time $T$ will converge. So the fact that the method comes up with an "approximate" solution as mentioned by the OP should be expected.